# Getting rows from several primary keys sql

Tags: sql, rows

i have theese tables:

```
Works
 ____________________________________________________________________
|                                                                   |
|id  user_id  cat_id  branch_id  country  budget  explanation       |
|___________________________________________________________________|

Categories
 ____________________________________________________________________
|                                                                   |
|id  category                                                       |
|___________________________________________________________________|

Categories_Branch
 ____________________________________________________________________
|                                                                   |
|id  cat_id  branch                                                 |
|___________________________________________________________________|


I want them displayed like this:
 ____________________________________________________________________
|                                                                   |
|id  country  budget  explanation  category  branch                 |
|___________________________________________________________________|
```

I cant get this to work, current sql is:

```
SELECT works.id, works.country, works.budget, works.explanation, categories.category, categories_branch.branch
FROM works, categories, categories_branch
WHERE works.user_id = ".$_SESSION['customer_id']."
AND works.cat_id = categories.id
AND categories_branch.cat_id = categories.id
GROUP BY works.id
```

This makes the branch group up wrong, displaying the wrong one.

Does anyone know how to solve this? All help is very appreciated.

**Edit**

Here's a image displaying how i want it ordered, the problem is that the wrong branch is displayed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JApkb.png

Comment: You need to JOIN the tables together instead of using all those WHERE clauses.

Comment: How are you doing `GROUP BY works.id` and still selecting other columns?

Comment: Remove the GROUP BY.  The WHERE's are clumsy and inefficient compared to using JOIN, but they should do the trick here.

Comment: @DavidStarkey, that's (unfortunately) valid in MySQL.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all your comments. I removed GROUP BY works.id and i tried JOIN, but i still get the same problem. The rows are not grouped up right, here is an picture showing results: http://imgur.com/QTKQV9L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with this, and go from there:

```
SELECT works.id, works.country, works.budget, works.explanation, categories.category, categories_branch.branch
FROM works
INNER JOIN categories ON works.cat_id = categories.id
INNER JOIN categories_branch ON categories_branch.cat_id = categories.id
WHERE works.user_id = ".$_SESSION['customer_id']."
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This works just like when i remove the GROUP BY in my query. But as i understand now this is a better way to do it. The problem is the query results is not grouped right. Here is a picture showing what i mean: http://imgur.com/QTKQV9L

Comment: How do you want it to be grouped?

Comment: I want it to be grouped by works, each work can have different categories / branches.

Comment: A simple ORDER BY ought to suffice.  Do you have a field that contains the work name?

Comment: If i ORDER BY works.id wich is the only identifier, it will display duplicate entries. Here is a picture showing the results http://i.imgur.com/wf7HhMr.png

I want the results to be like this, but with the right branch:
http://i.imgur.com/M7GIwlk.png

Comment: Looks it was just me being dumb, i forgot to add a identifier for the branch in the query. It now works, and i am using the JOIN example you posted. Thanks alot !